# Stacking two divs on top of one another, but facing cross-browser onclick/background image behavior issues

Tags: javascript, css

I'm working on a website that, when clicked anywhere, changes a single image. One div is layered underneath another, both of which cover the entire page, with spans containing the image and captions above all.

It works perfectly on Firefox, Chrome, and Opera. It's on Edge (aka IE) that it fails to show a background image or allow me to click on the background of my site and change the image. And on mobile, I'm having a similar issue with the onclick, except the background *does* show up. Backgrounds are set with javascript. My CSS for the two div elements is as follows.

```
.all {
height:100%;
width:100%;
background-size:cover;
position: absolute;
left:0;
top: 0;
}

.loading {
height:100%;
width:100%;
position: absolute;
z-index: 999;
left:0;
top: 0;
}
```

My javascript is [here](http://dreamquest.io/javascript.js), and the root of that is obviously my html.

I'm entirely new to all of this, so I'm sure I'm lacking understanding of divs or something, or lack of knowledge about cross-browser compatibility with these "elements"(?).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide link of working example or could create jsfiddle for this.

Comment: http://www.dreamquest.io/

Comment: There might be issue with css code and you can even check about filter browser support on caniuse.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why but it seems the `style` method does not work well in IE. Adding cssText works for me in IE11 (I haven't Edge):

```
document.getElementById("all").style.cssText= "height:100%; width:100%; background-size:cover; position: absolute; left:0; top: 0; -webkit-filter: blur(50px); -moz-filter: blur(50px); -o-filter: blur(50px); -ms-filter: blur(50px); filter: blur(50px);";
```

**PS**:
`<center>` tag is deprecated long time ago. Use css for center the elements.

Comment: Deprecated, but still working, so I'm not sure why I'd go through the trouble of adding individual margins on everything when I can just center the whole document basically with a fraction of the effort.

Comment: of course you can do whatever you want but it is a question of good practice to separate the presentation of content. In most situations can be replaced `<center>` by `.center { margin: auto; text-align: center; }`

Comment: Very nice, btw, your answer fixed it all. ^_^

Comment: I'm trying to add that `.center` selector to my CSS but after putting `center` classes in both of the relevant spans, it doesn't appear to be working. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: you can use a `div` with class `center` instead the `<center>` tag, you can do with the `span` but is a inline element, for it works you have to set `display:block`

Comment: Thank you, I finally understand the difference between `span` and `div`.